# Get previous year start month/date and end month/date

Tags: javascript, date

How can i get the previous `year` start `date/month` and end `date/month`

Below is the code, i have tried, but its not working...

```
var lastyear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
lastyear.setFullYear(lastyear.getFullYear() - 1);
var start = (new Date(lastyear, 0, 1)).getTime(),
    end = (new Date(lastyear, 11, 31)).getTime();
```

Technically i want `01/01/2015` to `12/31/2015`. What is the mistake i am doing here?

Comment: Define 'not working'?

Comment: You are passing `lastyear` (which is a Date object) as the first argument to `new Date()` instead of `lastyear.getFullYear()`. Make the first line `var lastyear = new Date().getFullYear() - 1` and omit the second line. Leave the remainder as–is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ran into issues because the you were using the Date() constructor incorrectly. According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp, the Date constructor accepts the following inputs:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

In your original code, you were passing a Date object into the "year" argument. I changed:

```
new Date(lastyear, 0, 1)
```

to

```
new Date(lastyear.getFullYear(), 0, 1)
```

which fixed the problem.

---

```
var lastyear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 1, 0, 1);
var start = (new Date(lastyear.getFullYear(), 0, 1)).getTime(),
    end = (new Date(lastyear.getFullYear(), 11, 31)).getTime();
```

Is this the solution you are looking for?

Comment: Which does not explain the OP's issue or how your code fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @RobG. I have updated the answer.